# What does mvn sonar:sonar do?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

What are the maven lifecycle phases does the command `mvn sonar:sonar` execute?

While I see the logs that run over the screen, at a very high level `test, install` that I spotted out.

Consider the following example,

I have a maven project like the following

```
maven-root

 maven-child-1

 maven-child-2
```

Consider the following scenario, I have done them sequentially at root level

1. `mvn clean install`
2. `mvn sonar:sonar`  -- See the report
3. Modified child-2 by adding some test cases to increase the code coverage
4. Run `mvn sonar:sonar`

My changes for the test cases are not reflecting in the report.

1. I have deleted the report from sonarqube
2. `mvn sonar:sonar`

Still that generates me the old report.

In brief, Do I need to perform `mvn clean install` and then `mvn sonar:sonar` ?

If `mvn sonar:sonar` covers executing the `mvn clean install`, why the report gives me old numbers?

Comment: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven

Comment: Thanks @DavidMays, it says "If possible, an install goal should be performed prior to the sonar:sonar one". I didn't understand what if not possible... any idea..

Comment: @dm78 link not working

Comment: @Gaurav The doc is now at [SonarQube Documentation → Analyzing Source Code → Scanners → SonarScanner for Maven](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/). The source is at https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-maven.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`mvn sonar:sonar` does not trigger a `mvn clean install` execution. It triggers a Maven Surefire plugin execution only.

This is why you need to perform a `mvn clean install` before each analysis - otherwise your compiled classes won't be up-to-date and therefore the Surefire execution won't include recent modifications.

Comment: I know, your answer is years ago but I bumped in the same thing and I'm wondering:
Will a `mvn clean verify` followed by `mn sonar:sonar` be sufficient? Or does it have to be an `isntall`?

Comment: @markus_ [SonarQube Documentation → Analyzing Source Code → Scanners → SonarScanner for Maven](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/) mentions both and for `install`: „_Be sure to use `install` as first step for multi-module projects_“. However, I can't comprehend what this has to do with multi-module projects. Since SQ analyzes [„• ... source code \[and\] • ... compiled code“](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/overview/#header-1) a `mvn test-compile` should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I re-read your first link to the documentation and it acutally now states, that `verify` in a non-multi module context is sufficient. I'm quite sure, it wasn't written that way half a year ago (-:  btw.: `test-compile` won't be sufficient, as the upload-data step takes place later. Test execution in `test` will be executed as well as you may want to record and upload test coverage.

Comment: @fabrice-sonarsource-team, I also realize that `sonar:sonar` also trigger Maven Failsafe plugin. Is there a way to not call it?

Answer (score 0):

**Run the below cammand**

mvn clean install sonar:sonar