# How to generate html report for issues reported using sonarqube-5.4 and maven?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I have checked the link:[sonarqube issues report](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Issues+Report+Plugin),but not clear on how to achive it during maven build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As documented the Issues Report Plugin is not compatible with versions 5.1 and greater. [SonarLint for Command-Line](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/SonarLint+for+Command+Line) should be used to get the same feature. It is simple to enable with Maven:

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true
```

Paths to the generated HTML reports are displayed in logs:

```
[INFO] HTML Issues Report generated: /xxx/target/sonar/issues-report/issues-report.html
[INFO] Light HTML Issues Report generated: /xxx/target/sonar/issues-report/issues-report-light.html
[INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: SonarLint for command line has been deprecated and is not longer available.

Answer (score 2):

Cycle of steps.

```
mvn clean install
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.issuesreport.html.enable=true
```

As per the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013399/what-does-mvn-sonarsonar-do), build should happen before the analysis. `sonar:sonar` triggers maven surefire plugin to execute.